# Dealing with very large video files in html 5

Tags: javascript, html, video, filereader

So I've been playing around with a certain idea. My plan was to use HTML5 drag and drop and the `FileReader()` API to let people upload video. I want to do some amount of client side processing to display the video. However, when I run the code I find that Chrome crashes. Is there a better way than file reader to deal with large video files?

Here is my example code:

```
function handle_video(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    elem = document.getElementById("dnd_dialog");
    elem.style.display="block";
    console.log(files);
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    document.getElementById("fname").value = files[0].name;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        document.getElementById("thumbnail_upload").src = reader.result;
    }, false);
  //    document.getElementById("thumbnail_upload").src = 
}
function drag_over(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use File blobs directly. No need for FileReader and by all means avoid Data-URIs (they are slow and the browser may impose length limits).

The browser will handle File blobs in a more fluid and intelligent way.

The key lines would be:

```
var fileBlob = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
var url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(fileBlob);

video.src = url;
```

Comment: For me, `e.dataTransfer.files[0]` is undefined. Why?